# What are the mandatory steps to import a module?

Tags: python, windows, import, module, scons

I'm new to python and I face an issue:

I try to extend my `SConstruct` file and to import a module located in a sub-directory of my project.

Here is my `SConstruct` file:

```
import os, sys
sys.path.append(os.path.abspath(os.path.join('.', 'custom_dir')))
import mymodule

mymodule.foo()
```

Here is the `mymodule.py` file, located into a subdirectory named `custom_dir`:

```
def foo():
  print 'foo'
```

I also have a `__init__.py` file in my `custom_dir` directory.

When I execute `scons`:

```
  File ".\SConstruct", line 22, in <module>
    mymodule.foo()
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'foo'
```

If I do `python.exe SConstruct` I got the same result.

What am I doing wrong here ?

Comment: Need a colon after `def foo()`.  What happens if you do `import mymodule` then `mymodule.__dict__` from Python's command line?

Comment: @Mike: I can load and use the module successfully from the command line, if I start the command line tool within the same directory than my module.

Comment: Actually, I was wondering what the output from `mymodule.__dict__` was, but it's moot now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should make sure that you are importing the correct module and not a different one with the same name somewhere else in your path

try running your program with `python.exe -v SConstruct`

or

`print mymodule.__file__` right before `print mymodule.foo()`

Comment: I had a directory with the same name than the module which was conflicting. Many thanks for this debugging technique ;)

Answer (score 1):

Beware path manipulation; trouble will find you.

Take a look at http://docs.python.org/tutorial/modules.html

I've set up what I think you are trying to do below. This should work.

File structure:

```
/SConstruct.py
/custom_dir/
/custom_dir/__init__.py
/custom_dir/mymodule.py
```

/custom_dir/__init__.py is blank

/custom_dir/mymodule.py:

```
def foo():
    print 'foo'
```

/SConstruct.py:

```
import custom_dir.mymodule as mymodule

mymodule.foo()
```

Comment: I get this: `AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'foo':
  File "C:\workbench\scons_test\SConstruct", line 18:
    mymodule.foo()`

Answer (score 0):

You can access SCons classes, e.g. Environment from modules other than SConstruct by including

```
from SCons.Script import *
```

See the documentation [here](http://www.scons.org/doc/1.2.0/HTML/scons-user/x3627.html#AEN3627).

Also, rather than using '.' to indicate the root of the build tree, you should be using [`Dir('#').path`](http://www.scons.org/wiki/Dir%28%29).